# Planar curve with width

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have a planar bezier curve, this curve is in general not closed but it can intersect itself.

What I want is to give this curve a finite width **in the plane of the curve**. I have found many ideas about giving a curve volume or extruding out of the plane of the curve but that's not what I need.

Is there a way to achieve a finite in-plane width (as if I was drawing the curve with a thick pencil) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can achieve this easily with bevel objects.

A *Bevel Object* defines a section to be swept or extruded along the curve object, if you want to add simple width to the curve object just create a simple linear bevel curve and use it as bevel object in your open curve.

Control the width of the 'ribbon' by controlling the size of the bevel curve

[image: Bevel Curve]