# How to extrude a Bezier curve to the right length?

Tags: modeling

So I plan on creating an animation involving the Nurburgring, I have outline the inside with a Bezier curve. Here is what it looks like.
  [image: Track from a side view]

[image: Track with the map in the background]

My question is how do I get the curves to extrude over the road part of the track? I can get it to fill the middle portion. (But it only has 1 face/vertices). If I need to go back around and do the outside rather than the inside of the track I still would like to know how to extrude it to the length I would like while also having it be a plain instead of a cube or cylinder, etc..

Comment: is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/planar-curve-with-width) what you mean?

Comment: Thank you Robin! I actually decided to just go ahead and build the outside again along with the inside and just fill that in which appears to have worked. However the post you linked will definitely come in handy

Comment: With the comment above after bevel you can convert to mesh